# How to fix '__curl_rule_01__' declared as an array with a negative size

Tags: xcode, xcode6, cocos2d-x

/Users/quddus/Documents/cocos2dx_lib/cocos2dx/platform/third_party/ios/curl/curlrules.h:143:6: '**curl_rule_01**' declared as an array with a negative size

I am using Cocos2dx and supporting 64 bit, i get this error when i switched to standard architectures, please help.